# how to kill background process in UWP c#?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP APP and a win32 process running as a background process.I want my UWP to kill the process in some cases. How to do it?

1. I have tried Process.GetProcesses(). It says that this operation is not supported on this platform.
2. I also tried ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForProcesses()。But **"IList infos = process.GetAppDiagnosticInfos()**" returns ***null***.

   ```
        IReadOnlyList<ProcessDiagnosticInfo> processes = ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForProcesses();
        if (processes != null)
        {
            foreach (ProcessDiagnosticInfo process in processes)
            {
                if(process.ExecutableFileName == backgroundProcessName)
                {
                    IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = process.GetAppDiagnosticInfos();
                    foreach (AppDiagnosticInfo info in infos)
                    {
                        IList< AppResourceGroupInfo> groups = info.GetResourceGroups();
                        foreach (AppResourceGroupInfo group in groups)
                        {
                            IAsyncOperation<AppExecutionStateChangeResult> result = group.StartTerminateAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
         }
   ```

Comment: Why do you want to kill it?

Comment: in case it's dead locked for some reason.

Comment: Is the background process one that you started via `FullTrustProcessLauncher`?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT yes, I started with FullTrustProcessLauncher

Comment: Do you have control over the code in the spawned process (can you add some new code), or is it something you cannot modify?